# Value of old foreign bills as collectibles

Tags: currency

I have several paper Francs and Marks from the 1930's and 40's. Do they have any value  as collectibles or legal tender?

Answer (score 1):

They would definitely have value as collectibles.

You need to check out with local dealers or coin shows on the value, in some countries ebay would have a section to sell coins and currencies. Alternatively  world of coins, or numismatica sites can help you.